# How to relay outbound request from docker container to modify headers?

Tags: docker, iptables, http-proxy, netcat, socat

I have an application that is running in Docker configured with an NGINX reverse proxy. The application is a binary, I don't have source code and there's no way to modify the header of an HTTP request from the app itself. My goal is to append a header field before the request is dispatched out of the host machine:

```
/// @dev some http proxy or similar
listener(PORT, function(request) {
  // 1) modifies header
  request.setHeader('FOO', 'bar')
  // 2) passes through to original or intended destination
  request.continue()
})
```

The key is to modify the request's header within the host machine where the Docker app is running.

I looked at MITM proxies and to reroute the Docker outbound traffic with iptables or socat.

Is there anything you would suggest for this operation?

Comment: Are you looking to build your own proxy from scratch, set up something else, or reconfigure your existing Nginx proxy?

Comment: It'd be great if something's already out there

Comment: NGINX can add headers both for [incoming requests](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) to the upstream and [responses back to client](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header). Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a header to an outgoing ***response***, simply use `add_header` directive:

```
location /foo/ {
  add_header name "value";
  proxy_pass http://my-legacy-app;
}
```

To add a header to an outgoing ***request*** you can try a forward proxy:

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.121:80;
  
  location / {
    proxy_add_header name "value";
    proxy_pass http://$http_host$request;
  }
}
```

This will work if you can make your application to send all outgoing requests to `127.0.0.121:80` (the forward proxy) instead of actual targets. For example you can make the legacy app container to use a dedicated DNS server, which will say that every host is on `127.0.0.121` (or any other value).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Traefik reverse proxy](https://traefik.io/traefik/) v2.4+ with [Traefik Pilot](https://traefik.io/traefik-pilot/) enabled and a plugin like [Header transformation](https://pilot.traefik.io/plugins/605afbd5a5f67ab9a1b0e537/header-transformation).

You run **Traefik** as a container which routes the traffic to the other containers. You can then link your instance to **Traefik Pilot** using a token, which enables plugins. If you use [labels](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#labels) in a **docker-compose.yml** file:

```yaml
services:
    traefik:
        # ...
        labels:
         - "--pilot.token=XXXXXXXX"
         # ...
```

To add the plugin you can also add labels to the **Traefik** service and to your app too:

```yaml
services:
    traefik:
        # ...
        labels:
         # ...
         - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
         - "--pilot.token=XXXXXXXX"
         - "--experimental.plugins.htransformation.modulename=github.com/tommoulard/htransformation"
         - "--experimental.plugins.htransformation.version=v0.2.3"

    your_service:
        # ...
        labels:
         - "traefik.enable=true"
         - "traefik.http.routers.your_service.rule=Host(`some.host`)"
         - "traefik.http.routers.your_service.entrypoints=web"
         - "traefik.http.routers.your_service.middlewares=add_header"
         - "traefik.http.middlewares.add_header.plugin.htransformation.Rules[0].Name=set_foo"
         - "traefik.http.middlewares.add_header.plugin.htransformation.Rules[0].Header=FOO"
         - "traefik.http.middlewares.add_header.plugin.htransformation.Rules[0].Value=bar"
         - "traefik.http.middlewares.add_header.plugin.htransformation.Rules[0].Type=Set"
```

You can also use other configuration files in **YAML** or **TOML**, everything is shown in the documentations.

Comment: This is really cool but too heavy since I'm already using NGINX. Makes a good point that solution should exist in NGINX

Comment: @aug2uag yes I have to agree that this is a bit heavy and verbose. I don't know to do it with NGINX but thanks for your feedback.